ControlClick does not work on particular area of the window
I want to automate the uninstall of Huorong Internet Security antivirus but the uninstaller does not support any /silent argument. The script clicks by coordinates because there is no control id or text visible using AutoIt window information tool.
;Wait for the uninstall window to appear
WinWait("Uninstalling")

; Activate the window
WinActivate("Uninstalling")
;Sleep(2000)
#RequireAdmin
; Send a mouse click at coordinates
ControlClick("Uninstalling", "", "", "primary", 10, 247 ,248)

The installer has buttons "uninstall" and "cancel". When I set coordinates to "cancel" the code works, but on "uninstall" nothing happened.
The uninstaller window
MouseClick() does not focus on the uninstall window. Only the "uninstall" button is having this issue.

does send("{TAB}{ENTER}") work?

If you want to automate install/uninstall windows then you need to run your AutoIt script as administrator. To do this add #RequireAdmin as first line in your script.
